# start multiple instances of a service on a standalone jboss

Tags: sidekiq, torquebox

We have torquebox 3.0.0 (build 75) running in a standalone configuration. We want to run multiple instances of a service, so we have a runtime pool defined as follows

pool :services do
    type :bounded
    min 5
    max 5
  end

I have torquebox backstage deployed to monitor the application. When deployed and run, we see 5 instances of the service in the pool, but only 1 stays in use while 4 show as available forever.

My questions are
- is it even possible to have multiple instances of the service in a standalone torquebox?
- do i have to set singleton to false to start multiple instances of the service?
- anything i am missing?